# Why this photo cannot opened on anywhere except google browser?

Tags: browser, images, photos, jpeg

https://wxiang.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/new/web/20230804/1691128104810-91071.jpg

Above is the address of the photo , you can download it and try to open it in any image software and google browser. google browser can open it , but others way even phone or image code util can not open it?

What is the reason and how can i fix it ? I accept some photos like this uploaded form mine website users sometimes, can I fix it with Java or Javascript ?

i have check this question but not help,the IrfanView cannot open the photo too..https://superuser.com/questions/334352/how-to-fix-an-image-that-doesnt-open-in-photoshop-even-though-it-opens-fine-in

By the way ,i can not upload the photo with this question too, the photo can show on the broswer but maybe the server dont think it is a qualified photo and reject it.
[here is the upload screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b56Do.png)

Comment: This isn’t a JPEG image. It’s a AVIF image.

Comment: Original link works just fine with Safari. Has been pointed out it’s not actually a .jpg file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I used to be fond of saying, file extensions lie. Rather than trusting the extension, its worth checking. The linux file command and the cross platform too TriD is what I'd use and the latter [has an online version](https://mark0.net/onlinetrid.py)

[image]

*That* tells me, as Daniel had pointed out in the comments that its most likely a AVIF image. You'd need to install the appropriate codec (like with the bad old days of windows) to be able to open it - with windows, there's a plugin available over [the MS store](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/av1-video-extension/9MVZQVXJBQ9V?hl=en-sg&gl=sg&rtc=1) called the AV1 video extension - and you'd need a software that supports it on your platform for other things. In windows, once the plugin is installed the native photos app, and anything using the native windows framework for this will be able to open it, and then you can convert it to a more common format.

I'm no programmer, but I'd probably wager once you know what codec/format it actually is, you might be able to find a library or format that can handle it for conversion

Imgur's likely rejecting it because its checking what type of file it is, and AVIFs are not actually supported.